# React: Loading scripts in <head> takes long time, cannot be used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load an external script in `<head>` like this:

```
<script async type='text/javascript' src='//externalprovider.net/our_script.js'></script>
```

This script declares a function `window.manager.loadFunction(sid, mid);` which I then use in some components like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.manager.loadFunction(this.props.ids[0], this.props.ids[1]);
}
```

My problem is that the script fetch from the exteral provider is slow enough so that the component has time to mount before the script is ready. This gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadFunction' of undefined`.

Just to check, I copied the full and script pasted it into the `<head>`, which worked exactly as expected. So my conclusion is that the script loads too slow from the external provider. Unfortunately this will not work for us, because the external provider needs to be able to change the script dynamically, so I can't have it hardcoded in our `<head>`.

So I thought that I would make a service that uses axios to load the script and then evaluates it, like this:

```
async getAdsScript() {
    try {
        const url = '//externalprovider.net/our_script.js';
        const src = (await axios.get(url)).data;
        const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        const newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');

        newScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScriptTag.async = true;
        newScriptTag.text = src;
        head.appendChild(newScriptTag);

        PubSub.publish('AdsScript.loaded', true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

I then want to use it like this:

```
loadFunction() {
    window.manager.loadFunction(this.props.ids[0], this.props.ids[1]);
}

componentDidMount() {
    PubSub.subscribe('AdsScript.loaded', (msg, showing) =>
        this.loadFunction());
}
```

But this did not work either, because I got a CORS error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://externalprovider.net/our_script.js' from origin 'https://dev.testserver.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and we cannot unfortunately ask them to add CORS policies to their servers.

Does anyone hav an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: An ugly workaround would be to wrap your window.manager.loadFunction() call in a setInterval and a try/catch. You keep trying to call that function until it works, then you clear the interval.

Comment: why not to load the script in App.js componentWillMount/DidMount?
You can also use crossorigin="anonymous" when loading the script

Comment: @Drusto was calling the load service from App.js componentDidMount, I want to keep App.js clean, that's why I have services loading all external resources. But I found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you have already answered, you can just remove the async attribute from script tag. But then your page will be blocked until the external script loads. If you will have a slow connection to the external server, this can lead to slow initialization of your app.

If you want to execute your JS code and render app until external script loads, you can make one of two things:

1. You can use the code that you wrote in question and set up Nginx on your side that will just proxy requests to the external server. After that, you will make a request to your Nginx to get the external code. This will fix the issue with CORS.

OR

2. You can use `Deferred` for waiting until the external script loads. You can find Deferred in some lib on npm or write by yourself. That's how it will look like:

```
<script>
    function Deferred() {
        let resolve = null;
        let reject = null;
        const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            resolve = res;
            reject = rej;
        });
        return {
            promise,
            resolve,
            reject
        }
    }

    window.waitForExternalScript = Deferred();

    function onExternalScriptLoad() {
        window.waitForExternalScript.resolve();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./your_main_script_here.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="//externalprovider.net/our_script.js" onload="onExternalScriptLoad()"></script>
```

And then in your app:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.waitForExternalScript.promise.then(() => {
        window.manager.loadFunction(this.props.ids[0], this.props.ids[1])
    })
}
```

Comment: @andrii-gobulenko I got another suggestion to use preload like this: <link rel="preload" href="//externalprovider.net/our_script.js" as="script">. Would you say that your solution above is better than this?

Comment: @BluePrint I think that using of  <link rel="preload" /> does not fix the problem with speed of initialization of the application. If your component that calls external code in componentDidMount is rendered when the application starts, then you need to wait until external lib code will load. Maybe the speed of application rendering is not critical for you. Moreover, if you don't update the external code version often, then you don't need to worry about this. Because your users will feel slow initialization and rendering only on first loading. Browsers cache code.

Comment: @andrii-gobulenko thanks. One more thing. Will your solution above work for every componentDidMount? Whan I mean is, if I have a component that is not mounted when the page loads but maybe some minutes after because the user goes to a certain page, will it work there also? And can I use the same in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: @BluePrint yes, you can use this solution in componentDidUpdate and in components that will be mounted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer was to remove `async` from the script tag in `<head>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//externalprovider.net/our_script.js'></script>
```

I didn't see that because I was staring myself blind on other parts of the code.